# pretty_print in etree.tostring() xml python

Tags: python, xml, pretty-print

I am trying to print out the xml doc with pretty_print option. But it thew an error

TypeError: tostring() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pretty_print'

Am I missing something here?

```
def CreateXML2():
    Date = etree.Element("Date", value=time.strftime(time_format, time.localtime()));
    UserNode = etree.SubElement(Date, "User");
    IDNode = etree.SubElement(UserNode, "ID");
    print(etree.tostring(Date, pretty_print=True));
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using `lxml.etree` (`lxml` library) and not `xml.etree.ElementTree` (the built-in `ElementTree` Python library)? The former has a `pretty_print` argument, but the latter does not.

Comment: I used xml.etree not lxml. So the xml.etree does not have pretty_print in its etree.tostring()??

Comment: No, it does not. Read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring), or even just run `help(etree.tostring)` in a console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty printing XML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the problem is that `ElementTree` library doesn't support pretty printing. A workaround, as explained [here](https://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/create.html#pretty-printing-xml) is to reparse the output string from `ElementTree` in another library that provides support for pretty printing.

Comment: @mastashake57 Oh, yes, there are a lot of race conditions in this site.

Comment: The link is not working for me, is it working for someone?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python) within StackOverflow?  I think it covers what you want:

## in-place prettyprint formatter

```
def indent(elem, level=0):
    i = "\n" + level*"  "
    if len(elem):
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
            elem.text = i + "  "
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
        for elem in elem:
            indent(elem, level+1)
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = i
```

That sample code was from the post and from [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm#prettyprint)

Also, for additional information, you're not calling the tostring() method properly.  Have a look at [Python's website](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring)  for more information.