# How to indent attributes in when prettyprinting xml in python?

Tags: python, lxml, pretty-print

Suppose I have XML like this:

```
 <graph label="Test" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:cy="http://www.cytoscape.org" xmlns="http://www.cs.rpi.edu/XGMML"  directed="1">
    <foo>...</foo>
 </graph>
```

The first element name with all its attributes  all appear on one line.

I have seen how to pretty print the element tree, using lxml, with  code like this:

```
from lxml import etree
 ...
def prettyPrintXml(filePath):
    assert filePath is not None
    parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False, remove_blank_text=True, 
                             strip_cdata=False)
    document = etree.parse(filePath, parser)
    print(etree.tostring(document, pretty_print=True, encoding='utf-8'))
```

... but using that, every element appears on one line.

Is there a magic incantation to tell the pretty printer to insert newlines between the element attributes so that, for example, the line length does not exceed 80 characaters?

I would like the result to look something like this:

```
<graph label="Test"
       xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
       xmlns:cy="http://www.cytoscape.org"
       xmlns="http://www.cs.rpi.edu/XGMML"  directed="1">
  <foo>...</foo>
</graph>
```

ps: I don't want to resort to [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) and `xmllint`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lxml` has a pretty print function built in: [here's a tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) which describes several ways to print xml. It has some [limitations](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#why-doesn-t-the-pretty-print-option-reformat-my-xml-output) (limitations in the xml specs, according to lxml), though.

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python) has several answers with more or less hacky solutions to pretty print xml, and I think you could model at least the regexp based answer to suit your needs.

[Fredrik Lundh](http://effbot.org) (of [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) fame) has a very low-level description for [printing xml](http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm#prettyprint), which you could also customize to newline and indent attributes.