# Creating XML files without Labelimg in Tensorflow Object Detection

Tags: xml, tensorflow, label, object-detection

I want to run my own dataset and want to create the XML files by myself since there are too many and it is not possible with the `labelimg` software.
I already have the coordinates of bonding boxes and have written a script by which I create the XML files.

Here is an example of the created XML files:
I have around 400 training images - each with 20-30 objects in it.
But after running the code of "xml_to_csv.py", I get the following error (in the attachment also). While it is not there when I run it with a labelimg-created XML.

This is the error:

[image]

This is my generated XML file:

[image: This is my generated XML file:]

And this is in the continue   :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYhPm.jpg)[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuK66.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use a safe way to generate **LabelImg** `xml` files which may reduce possible chance of data format error. I found this ways useful for me to avoid error due to *xml standard*.

```py
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from PIL import Image


def create_labimg_xml(image_path, annotation_list):

    image_path = Path(image_path)
    img = np.array(Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB'))

    annotation = ET.Element('annotation')
    ET.SubElement(annotation, 'folder').text = str(image_path.parent.name)
    ET.SubElement(annotation, 'filename').text = str(image_path.name)
    ET.SubElement(annotation, 'path').text = str(image_path)

    source = ET.SubElement(annotation, 'source')
    ET.SubElement(source, 'database').text = 'Unknown'

    size = ET.SubElement(annotation, 'size')
    ET.SubElement(size, 'width').text = str (img.shape[1])
    ET.SubElement(size, 'height').text = str(img.shape[0])
    ET.SubElement(size, 'depth').text = str(img.shape[2])

    ET.SubElement(annotation, 'segmented').text = '0'

    for annot in annotation_list:
        tmp_annot = annot.split(',')
        cords, label = tmp_annot[0:-2], tmp_annot[-1]
        xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = cords[0], cords[1], cords[4], cords[5]

        object = ET.SubElement(annotation, 'object')
        ET.SubElement(object, 'name').text = label
        ET.SubElement(object, 'pose').text = 'Unspecified'
        ET.SubElement(object, 'truncated').text = '0'
        ET.SubElement(object, 'difficult').text = '0'

        bndbox = ET.SubElement(object, 'bndbox')
        ET.SubElement(bndbox, 'xmin').text = str(xmin)
        ET.SubElement(bndbox, 'ymin').text = str(ymin)
        ET.SubElement(bndbox, 'xmax').text = str(xmax)
        ET.SubElement(bndbox, 'ymax').text = str(ymax)

    tree = ET.ElementTree(annotation)
    xml_file_name = image_path.parent / (image_path.name.split('.')[0]+'.xml')
    tree.write(xml_file_name)


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# a quadrilateral bounding box(8 points) coordinate example
anotation_list = ['291,473,385,481,383,504,289,496,Hello',
                  '270,507,330,507,330,516,270,516,SUPERLATIVE']

create_labimg_xml('data/demo.jpg', anotation_list)
```

Comment: any idea how to format the xml file generated by this code?

Comment: Would you please try `BeautifulSoup` like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37892959/4257991

Comment: It does not work with tree.write. Let us know here If you find a something.