# Python: how to edit element of XML file?

Tags: python, xml

I have an `XML` file, This file includes many named elements, each element has several `nodes` under it:

```
<name search = "select ARG: write">
    <version id = "1.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
<name search = "select ARG: bla">
    <version id = "2.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
```

I want to search this `XML` file and in case this name search value starts with `select ARG` (in my example this the first value is `select ARG: write`) i want to create this new named element but this time the value that was `select ARG: write` should be `selected ARG: write`. This is what I have tried:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xamlfile = r'C:\file.xml'
newxamlfile = r'C:\new.xml'

dom = minidom.parse(xamlfile)

# Fetch the desired elements in the tree.
res = dom.getElementsByTagName('name')

# Loop through all.
for element in res:
    search_name_value = element.getAttribute('search')

    # Filter for the attribute and value.
    if search_name_value.startswith('select ARG:'):
        # In case of match, replace.
        element.setAttribute('search_name', search_name_value.replace('select ARG:', 'selected ARG:'))

# Store the file.
with open(newxamlfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(dom.toxml())
```

Here, I have replaced the desired string and not added the new one, editing the elements that I want instead of creating new ones and adding them to the file.

Any suggestions how to do that?

**UPDATE**

This is my file before:

```
<project version="4">
<name search="select ARG: write">
    <version id="1.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
<name search="select ARG: bla">
    <version id="2.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
</project>
```

This is how i want my file will be:

```
<project version="4">
<name search="select ARG: write">
    <version id="1.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
<name search="selected ARG: write">
    <version id="1.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
<name search="select ARG: bla">
    <version id="2.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
<name search="selected ARG: bla">
    <version id="2.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
</project>
```

**EDIT**

According `@DirtyBit` suggestion:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse(xamlfile)

tags = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("name")

for item in tags:
    str = item.attributes["search"].value
    if 'select ARG' in str:
        item.attributes["search"].value = item.attributes["search"].value.replace('select ARG', 'selected ARG')

with open(xamlfile, "a+") as f:
    xmldoc.writexml(f)
```

This works fine but i have 2 issues:

1. As you can see i added if statement because i want to duplicate and create new node only in the value is with `select ARG` (and replace it with `selected ARG`) and not duplicate the others that did not mach this conditions.
2. At he middle of the new XML file i have this line:

   `</element><?xml version="1.0" ?><element>`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want to do.  Could you edit your question to include your desired output?

Comment: @falukky for your first query, put an `if-block` before replacing the values to make sure the `search` attrib has `select ARG` only. and for the second one, you could try parsing the `xmldoc` content before and then maybe slice the first `22` chars to remove the `version` tag.

Answer (score 3):

Solution to replace part of an attribute (before update with new requirements):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('example.xml')

for name in tree.getroot().iterfind('name'):
    if name.attrib['search'].startswith('select ARG'):
        name.attrib['search'] = name.attrib['search'].replace(
            'select ARG', 'selected ARG')

tree.write('example.xml')
```

Solution to append new identical blocks with same replace on attribute as the above solution:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('example.xml')

for name in tree.getroot().iterfind('name'):
    if name.attrib['search'].startswith('select ARG'):
        new = ET.Element(name.tag)
        new.attrib['search'] = name.attrib['search'].replace(
            'select ARG', 'selected ARG')
        tree.getroot().append(new)
        for version in name.iterfind('version'):
            new.append(version)

tree.write('example.xml')
```

From the [ElementTree documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

> **parse(source, parser=None)** 
> Loads an external XML section into this element tree. source is a file name or file object. parser is an
>   optional parser instance. If not given, the standard XMLParser parser
>   is used. Returns the section root element.
>
> **getroot()** 
> Returns the root element for this tree.
>
> **iterfind(match)** 
> Finds all matching subelements, by tag name or path. Same as getroot().iterfind(match). Returns an iterable yielding
>   all matching elements in document order.
>
> **attrib** 
> A dictionary containing the element’s attributes. Note that while the attrib value is always a real mutable Python dictionary, an
>   ElementTree implementation may choose to use another internal
>   representation, and create the dictionary only if someone asks for it.
>   To take advantage of such implementations, use the dictionary methods
>   below whenever possible.
>
> **class xml.etree.ElementTree.Element(tag, attrib={}, **extra)** 
> Element class. This class defines the Element interface, and provides
>   a reference implementation of this interface.
>
> The element name, attribute names, and attribute values can be either
>   bytestrings or Unicode strings. tag is the element name. attrib is an
>   optional dictionary, containing element attributes. extra contains
>   additional attributes, given as keyword arguments.
>
> **append(subelement)**
>   Adds the element subelement to the end of this elements internal list of subelements
>
> **write(file, encoding="us-ascii", xml_declaration=None, default_namespace=None, method="xml")**
>  Writes the element tree to a
>   file, as XML. file is a file name, or a file object opened for
>   writing. encoding [1] is the output encoding (default is US-ASCII).
>   xml_declaration controls if an XML declaration should be added to the
>   file. Use False for never, True for always, None for only if not
>   US-ASCII or UTF-8 (default is None). default_namespace sets the
>   default XML namespace (for “xmlns”). method is either "xml", "html" or
>   "text" (default is "xml"). Returns an encoded string.

Comment: This works fine but i want to keep the old elements  and add the new, in the example i provide i have xml file with 2 'name ' element so the results should be xml file with 4 'name ' element

Answer (score 1):

The code below clone the requested elements and append them to the end of document.

**55394530.xm**l is a file that contains the data taken from the example XML

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import copy
from xml.dom import minidom

tree = ET.parse('55394530.xml')

names_to_duplicate = [e for e in tree.findall('.//name') if e.attrib.get('search').startswith('select ARG:')]
for name in names_to_duplicate:
    clone = copy.deepcopy(name)
    clone.attrib['search'] = clone.attrib['search'].replace('select', 'selected')
    tree.getroot().append(clone)

xmlstr = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(tree.getroot())).toprettyxml()
with open('out.xml', 'w') as out:
    out.write(xmlstr)
```

Output

```
<element>
    <name search="select ARG: 123">
        <version id="1.1.1">
            <value>bla</value>
            <method>blabla</method>
        </version>
    </name>
    <name search="select ARG: 456">
        <version id="1.1.1">
            <value>bla</value>
            <method>blabla</method>
        </version>
        <version id="1.1.1">
            <value>bla</value>
            <method>blabla</method>
        </version>
        <version id="1.1.1">
            <value>bla</value>
            <method>blabla</method>
        </version>
    </name>
    <name search="text ARG: 789">
        <version id="1.1.1">
            <value>bla</value>
            <method>blabla</method>
        </version>
    </name>
    <name search="foo ARG: 444">
        <version id="1.1.1">
             <value>bla</value>
            <method>blabla</method>
        </version>
    </name>
    <name search="test ARG: Cancel">
        <version id="1.1.1">
            <value>bla</value>
            <method>blabla</method>
        </version>
    </name>
<name search="selected ARG: 123">
        <version id="1.1.1">
            <value>bla</value>
            <method>blabla</method>
        </version>
    </name>
    <name search="selected ARG: 456">
        <version id="1.1.1">
            <value>bla</value>
            <method>blabla</method>
        </version>
        <version id="1.1.1">
            <value>bla</value>
            <method>blabla</method>
        </version>
        <version id="1.1.1">
            <value>bla</value>
            <method>blabla</method>
        </version>
    </name>
    </element>
```

Comment: i cannot see that the file changed ? nothing added

Comment: `ET.dump(tree)`  is printing the modified xml to the console. The last element are the cloned nodes. Can you see them? (See the output in my answer)

Comment: Yes i can see and this looks fine, how to write it now ?

Comment: Do you want to save it to a file?

Comment: `xmlstr = ET.tostring(tree.getroot(), encoding='utf8', method='xml')` will convert the XML to a string. All you have to do is to write this string to a file. (I assume you know how to write a string to a file)

Comment: like this: with open('c:\file.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(xmlstr))

Comment: I can see all the new line characters in my file, why ?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813876/how-do-i-get-pythons-elementtree-to-pretty-print-to-an-xml-file/28814053

Comment: I try but i did not understand what do to

Comment: I have modified the code and now it writes the output to a file.

Comment: Any reason why i have now 2 empty lines after every line ?

Answer (score 0):

Using minidom, once you have the new elements, open the file in append mode `a+` and write to it:

**list.txt (before)**:

```
<project version="4">
<name search="select ARG: write">
    <version id="1.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
<name search="select ARG: bla">
    <version id="2.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
</project>
```

**Hence**:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('list_test.xml')

tags = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("name")

for item in tags:
    item.attributes["search"].value = item.attributes["search"].value.replace(
        'select ARG', 'selected ARG')

with open("list_test.xml", "a+") as f:
    xmldoc.writexml(f)
```

**list.txt (after)**:

```
<project version="4">
<name search="select ARG: write">
    <version id="1.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
<name search="select ARG: bla">
    <version id="2.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
</project><?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project version="4">
<name search="selected ARG: write">
    <version id="1.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
<name search="selected ARG: bla">
    <version id="2.0.0">
        <value>myVal</value>
        <method>myMethod</method>
    </version>
</name>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use lxml, here's a solution that uses an XPath predicate to check the `search` attribute value.

After selecting the correct `name` element, it makes a copy and then updates the attribute value.

It then adds the new `name` element after the original `name` element.

**XML Input** (input.xml)

```xml
<project version="4">
    <name search="select ARG: write">
        <version id="1.0.0">
            <value>myVal</value>
            <method>myMethod</method>
        </version>
    </name>
    <name search="select ARG: bla">
        <version id="2.0.0">
            <value>myVal</value>
            <method>myMethod</method>
        </version>
    </name>
</project>
```

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree
from copy import deepcopy

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

for name in tree.xpath("//name[starts-with(@search,'select ARG')]"):
    new_name = deepcopy(name)
    new_name.attrib["search"] = name.get("search").replace("select ARG", "selected ARG")
    name.addnext(new_name)

tree.write("output.xml")
```

**XML Output** (output.xml w/slight formatting changes for readability)

```xml
<project version="4">
    <name search="select ARG: write">
        <version id="1.0.0">
            <value>myVal</value>
            <method>myMethod</method>
        </version>
    </name>
    <name search="selected ARG: write">
        <version id="1.0.0">
            <value>myVal</value>
            <method>myMethod</method>
        </version>
    </name>
    <name search="select ARG: bla">
        <version id="2.0.0">
            <value>myVal</value>
            <method>myMethod</method>
        </version>
    </name>
    <name search="selected ARG: bla">
        <version id="2.0.0">
            <value>myVal</value>
            <method>myMethod</method>
        </version>
    </name>
</project>
```