# create an xml file using python

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am working on a project where it's required xml files to be generated.
I made a code to perform the xml but I am facing an issue with my output.
I am trying to iterate through csv file and convert it to xml

my code

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import zip_longest
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import os
df= pd.read_csv('detector.csv')
df.head()

df1= df['id'].astype(str)
df2=df['lane'].astype(str)
df3=df['pos'].astype(str)
df4=df['freq'].astype(str)
df5=df['file'].astype(str)

df_all= list(zip_longest(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5))

for i, j, k, l, m in df_all:
    root=Element('additional')
    tree=ElementTree(root)
    child= SubElement(root, 'e1Detector')
    child.set('id', i)
    child.set('lane', j)
    child.set('pos', k)
    child.set('freq', l)
    child.set('file', m)
   
    print(etree.tostring(root))
    tree.write('detector.add.xml')
```

what I get is only the last line of my csv file.

```
<additional>
<e1Detector id="e1Detector_77317_2_5" lane="77317_2" pos="1.51" freq="900.0" file="e1Detector_77317_2_5.xml" />
</additional>
```

what I want is this

```
<additional>
<e1Detector id="e1Detector_77305_1_1" lane="77305_1" pos="11.11" freq="900.0" file="e1Detector_77305_1_1.xml" />
<e1Detector id="e1Detector_77305_2_2" lane="77305_2" pos="11.11" freq="900.0" file="e1Detector_77305_2_2.xml" />
<e1Detector id="e1Detector_77317_0_3" lane="77317_0" pos="2.99" freq="900.0" file="e1Detector_77317_0_3.xml" />
<e1Detector id="e1Detector_77317_1_4" lane="77317_1" pos="2.06" freq="900.0" file="e1Detector_77317_1_4.xml" />
<e1Detector id="e1Detector_77317_2_5" lane="77317_2" pos="1.51" freq="900.0" file="e1Detector_77317_2_5.xml" />
</additional>
```

I tried using append but it didn't work

you can find my csv file [here](https://github.com/waed1110/sample1/blob/166a3be50b1a7944a35bf3515b8ea77a8f4798c8/detector.csv)

Comment: your "tree.write" call is inside the loop (!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to move the tree and root elements out of the loop, aswell as writing the file:

```
root=Element('additional')
tree=ElementTree(root)

for i, j, k, l, m in df_all:
    child= SubElement(root, 'e1Detector')
    child.set('id', i)
    child.set('lane', j)
    child.set('pos', k)
    child.set('freq', l)
    child.set('file', m)

print(etree.tostring(root))
tree.write('detector.add.xml')
```

otherwise you just overwrite the file with each run of the loop.

Comment: thanks man, that worked. one more question please, how to make new line after each iteration?

Comment: @waed1110 maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813876/how-do-i-get-pythons-elementtree-to-pretty-print-to-an-xml-file could help you there.

Comment: thank you very much, I appreciate your help. I am new to programming and your contribution helped me and saved lots of time for me. thanks again