# How to create XML file using Python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, pretty-print

I would like to create an XML file.
I tried it but the format looks bad, it only shows in one line.

Here is it:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element("data")
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "status", date="20210123")

ET.SubElement(doc, "name", name="john").text = "some value1"
ET.SubElement(doc, "class", name="abc").text = "some vlaue2"

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("FILE.xml")
```

The output is:

```
<data><status date="20210123"><name name="john">some value1</name><class name="abc">some vlaue2</class></status></data>
```

But my expectation output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<data>
     <status>
          <name name="john">some value1</name>
          <class name="abc">some vlaue2</class>
     </status>
</data>
```

Anyone can give me an idea, please. I really appreciated it. Thank you

Comment: why it is important? who needs to read this file? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813876/how-do-i-get-pythons-elementtree-to-pretty-print-to-an-xml-file

Comment: In Python 3.9, you can pretty-print with ElementTree: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.indent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to

1. Use `ET.tostring()` to get your xml as a string
2. Use `xml.dom.minidom` to get a *DOM object* from the string
3. Use `toprettyxml()` of DOM object to get the xml as formatted string
4. Add encoding information to the xml declaration part by simply splitting and concating the formatted string
5. Write the string to a file

Code:

```py
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import xml.dom.minidom

m_encoding = 'UTF-8'

root = ET.Element("data")
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "status", date="20210123")
ET.SubElement(doc, "name", name="john").text = "some value1"
ET.SubElement(doc, "class", name="abc").text = "some vlaue2"

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root))
xml_string = dom.toprettyxml()
part1, part2 = xml_string.split('?>')

with open("FILE.xml", 'w') as xfile:
    xfile.write(part1 + 'encoding=\"{}\"?>\n'.format(m_encoding) + part2)
    xfile.close()
```

**Output file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<data>
    <status date="20210123">
        <name name="john">some value1</name>
        <class name="abc">some vlaue2</class>
    </status>
</data>
```

Comment: Yeah! This is it. Perfect. Thank you so much Buddy :)

Comment: Please check this post if you don't mind. Thanks in advance :)
https://stackoverflow.com/q/66671021/11076819