# Add " encoding="utf-8"?> to xml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I am creating an `xml` file, I just want that it should say this on the top

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

For now it says only

`<?xml version="1.0" ?>`

This is how I am creating it.

```
xmlstr = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root)).toprettyxml(indent="   ")
with open("Test.xml", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(xmlstr)
```

Comment: Did you copy that code from another SO question? The accepted answer there is wrong. There's no reason to convert the parsed XML data in root into a string only to parse it again with minidom to generate *another* string. The [*other* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68618047/134204) is better. `ET.indent(tree, space="\t", level=0)` to indent, `tree.write(file_name, encoding="utf-8")` to write

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: It works if you have Python 3.9. The OP uses Python 3.7. This answer is even better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63373633/407651

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to add `encoding` parameter:

```
xmlstr = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root)).toprettyxml(indent="   ", encoding="utf-8")
```

change "w" in the file save to "wb".

And, as suggested in the comments, to drop spurious parsing back to XML:

```
from lxml import etree

xml_object = etree.tostring(root,
                            pretty_print=True,
                            xml_declaration=True,
                            encoding='UTF-8')
```

Then it is enough to write `xml_object` to the file.

Comment: And probably remove `minidom` as well.  The question's code writes the DOM into a string only to parse it back into a DOM to write it back to a string. Looks like that code was copy-pastaed from another SO question

Comment: @AbhishekRai don't use *two* parsers. Use either `minidom` or `ElementTree`. If you already use `ElementTree` you can indent and output the XML string using only ET methods

Comment: @AbhishekRai your code is identical to other SO questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236395/discussion-between-abhishek-rai-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 2):

By adding the `encoding` argument you will get a byte string (that is why you have to change a file writing argument to binary mode). To return a string as you originally wanted and in the same time getting `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, you may use the following code:

```
xmlstr = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root)).toprettyxml(indent="   ", encoding="utf-8").decode("utf-8")
```