Python script to create an XML
I am preparing a Python script to create an XML like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FileInfo>
    <FileFormatVersion>1.0</FileFormatVersion>
    <CustomerName>GCS0223</CustomerName>
    <Source>nA</Source>
</FileInfo>
<Orders>
  <Item>
    <OrderCount>1</OrderCount>

I copied a script from the forum and it's working well, except I have some additional formatting questions. Here is my working code
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("FileInfo")
#doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc")

ET.SubElement(root, "FileFormatVersion").text = "1.0"
ET.SubElement(root, "CustomerName").text = "GCS0223"
ET.SubElement(root, "Source").text = "nA"
ET.SubElement(root, "OrderCount").text = "1"

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write(r'c:\AH_Output\IGW.xml')

How can I indent my "OrderCount" Under "Orders" and "Item" like this:
<Orders>
  <Item>
    <OrderCount>1</OrderCount>


Use the indent() function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68618047/407651

Note that xml.etree.cElementTree is deprecated. Just use xml.etree.ElementTree. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Add indentation as needed using the tail element field
ind = '  '
root = ET.Element("FileInfo")
root.tail = f"\n{ind}"

ele1 = ET.SubElement(root, "FileFormatVersion")
ele1.text = "1.0"
ele1.tail = f"\n{ind}{ind}"

Using lxml package instead could give a formatted xml with tostring method
xml = etree.tostring(element, pretty_print=True)


import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def create_xml():
    # Create the root element
    root = ET.Element("root")
    
    # Create a child element
    child1 = ET.SubElement(root, "child1")
    child1.text = "This is child 1"
    
    # Create another child element with an attribute
    child2 = ET.SubElement(root, "child2")
    child2.set("attribute", "value")
    child2.text = "This is child 2"
    
    # Create a sub-child element
    subchild = ET.SubElement(child2, "subchild")
    subchild.text = "This is a subchild of child 2"
    
    # Convert the tree to a string
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write("output.xml", encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_xml()
    print("XML file created successfully!")


This does not answer the question.

To properly encode your xml file you have like Tanish Sharma send, set the encoding in "utf-8" but mostly don't set allways root has parent but the correct parent element,
You can so just look at the above code and modify your code to add some litle thing,
(it's my first time so sorry if my response is not clear ^^')

This does not answer the question.
