# Use xml.etree.ElementTree to print nicely formatted xml files

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to write out xml files with Python. The issue is that they keep getting generated in a single line. I want to be able to easily reference them so if it's possible I would really like to be able to have the file written out cleanly.

This is what I am getting:

```
<Language><En><Port>Port</Port><UserName>UserName</UserName></En><Ch><Port>IP地址</Port><UserName>用户名称</UserName></Ch></Language>
```

This is what I would like to see:

```
<Language>
    <En>
        <Port>Port</Port>
        <UserName>UserName</UserName>
    </En>
    <Ch>
        <Port>IP地址</Port>
        <UserName>用户名称</UserName>
    </Ch>
</Language>
```

Comment: This is not a true duplicate: The other question leaves the possibility to use _any_ XML library. This question asks specifically for a solution when you are already working with the _built-in element tree_ library. Imho it makes perfect sense to ask this question specifically for this library, because it is apparently a missing feature!?

Comment: you can use a function like the one i found here: http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm#prettyprint

Comment: @bluenote10 When someone report, the other people will re-report, just to follow something. I'm from Colombia, so sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Related: [Python Bug Tracker - Issue report for Pretty Printing](https://bugs.python.org/issue14465); and [GitHub - proposed pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/4016).

Comment: You can check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63373633/268627. As of Python 3.9 there will be a new indent function built-in.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use the function [`toprettyxml()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.toprettyxml) from [`xml.dom.minidom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) in order to do that:

```
def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="\t")
```

The idea is to print your `Element` in a string, parse it using minidom and convert it again in XML using the `toprettyxml` function.

Source: http://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/create.html

Comment: This adds extra lines.  Not sure I'd call that pretty.

Comment: For a large file though this requires reparsing the whole XML. hmm...

Comment: @steve: Not only does that add another line, the data is processed like this: convert the XML tree to string, convert it back to an XML tree, and then convert it back to a string. That's not pretty, that's completely out of the question.

Comment: At least it works out of the box with a normal Python installation.

Comment: @RaúlSalinas-Monteagudo Not for my Python installation. Unfortunately I have the displeasure of working in an environment where lxml, bs4, xmltodict, stdio, numpy, etc. don't exist and can't be easily installed. Sorry just ranting... Now if only I could find a one-line solution for an out-dated and unsupported Python 2.7...

Comment: This answer does not refer to `xml.etree`.

Comment: @buhtz `ElementTree` is imported from `xml.etree`

Answer (score 24):

You could use the library [lxml](https://lxml.de/index.html) (Note top level link is now spam) , which is a superset of ElementTree. Its 
tostring() method includes a parameter [pretty_print](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-element-class) - for example:

```
>>> print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
<root>
  <child1/>
  <child2/>
  <child3/>
</root>
```

Comment: "pretty_print=True" does not work for me, and I do not why

Comment: etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True).decode() works!

Comment: Yes. But [lxml](https://lxml.de/) does not support default namespace very well.

Comment: It supportds namespaces much better than other libraries :) Also that link is now dead and a spam

Comment: This answer does not refer to `xml.etree`.

Comment: @buhtz No but it does tell you how to get a prettyprint without changing much code - only need to change the import rather than using minidom which has a totally different API