# How to save data in xml

Tags: python, xml, dataset

I want to save data in xml in this format

```
<posts>
    <row Id="1" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="13" 
         CreationDate="2010-09-13T19:16:26.763" Score="297" ViewCount="472045" 
         Body="&lt;p&gt;This is a common question by those who have just rooted their phones.  What apps, ROMs, benefits, etc. do I get from rooting?  What should I be doing now?&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" 
         OwnerUserId="10" 
         LastEditorUserId="16575" LastEditDate="2013-04-05T15:50:48.133" 
         LastActivityDate="2018-05-19T19:51:11.530" 
         Title="I've rooted my phone.  Now what?  What do I gain from rooting?" 
         Tags="&lt;rooting&gt;&lt;root-access&gt;" 
         AnswerCount="3" CommentCount="0" FavoriteCount="194" 
         CommunityOwnedDate="2011-01-25T08:44:10.820" />
</posts>
```

I tried this, but I don't know how will I save in the above format:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element("posts")
row = ET.SubElement(root, "row")

ET.SubElement(row, questionText = "questionText").text = questionText
            ET.SubElement(row, votes = "votes").text = votes
            ET.SubElement(row, tags = "tags").text = tags

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
            tree.write("data.xml")
```

Comment: Can you share how does the input data looks like ?

Comment: actually i am scrapping from web and want to save in xml.

Comment: Your code has at least several indentation errors - please fix. Show the output you get. Make your code a [mre] - currently I can not copy/paste it and run it to get any output at all because of the idnentation problems.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for `SubElement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement) say it has the following arguments: `parent, tag, attrib={}, **extra`.

You omit the `tag`, so you get an error `TypeError: SubElement() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)` with your code. You need something like:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element("posts")
row = ET.SubElement(root, "row", attrib={"foo":"bar", "baz":"qux"})

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("data.xml")
```

Outputs: `<posts><row baz="qux" foo="bar" /></posts>`

Comment: wow perfect! it works perfect as i wanted but it only prints one line. I want to print   multiple lines. i mean if there are 20 lines to print it writes 20.. i added it in loop

Comment: If you're talking about the formatting of the XML file, there a re a number of options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402323/use-xml-etree-elementtree-to-print-nicely-formatted-xml-files