# How to unpack values from a dataframe to xml

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Field':['FAPERF','FAPERF','FAPERF','FAPERF'],
           'Form':['LIVERID','LIVERID','LIVERID','LIVERID'],
           'Folder':['ALL','ALL','ALL','ALL'],
           'Logline':['9','9','9','10'],
           'Data':['Yes','Blank','No','Yes']})
```

I have to invoke these values to a xml files in the format as below

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ODM xmlns="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3" xmlns:mdsol="http://www.mdsol.com/ns/odm/metadata"
     ODMVersion="1.3" CreationDateTime="2019-10-25T07:29:41.711-00:00"
     FileOID="9a49b521-41ca-4b4b-81f1-9eae73df1c99" FileType="Transactional">
    <ClinicalData StudyOID="D933LC00001(DEV)" MetaDataVersionOID="1">
        <SubjectData SubjectKey="E888017" TransactionType="Update">
            <SiteRef LocationOID="9999 - A Site"/>
            <StudyEventData StudyEventOID="VISIT1" TransactionType="Update">
                <FormData FormOID="DM" TransactionType="Update">
                    <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="DM" TransactionType="Upsert">
                        <ItemData ItemOID="SEX" Value="C16576" TransactionType="Context">
                            <mdsol:Query Recipient="Site" Value="Analyse the race value"
                                         Status="Open"/>
                        </ItemData>
                    </ItemGroupData>
                </FormData>
            </StudyEventData>
        </SubjectData>
    </ClinicalData>
</ODM>
```

The code i have written so far is below

```py
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
import datetime
import openpyxl, smtplib, sys
#from ElementTree import prettify

generated_on = str(datetime.datetime.now())

root = Element('ODM')
root.set('version', '1.0')
#def alldata(Form, Logline, Data, Field, Folder): 
for i in length (final_intermediate1):   
    SubjectData=SubElement(ClinicalData, 'SubjectData', {'text':Form(i)})
    SiteRef =SubElement(SubjectData, 'SiteRef', {'text':Logline(i)})
    StudyEventData =SubElement(SiteRef, 'StudyEventData', {'text':Data(i)})
    FormData =SubElement(StudyEventData, 'FormData', {'text':Field(i)})
    ItemGroupData =SubElement(FormData, 'ItemGroupData', {'text':Folder(i)})
    #ClinicalData=SubElement(root, 'ClinicalData')

print prettify(root)
```

Not sure how to unpack the values form dataframe and invoke them to xml. I am stuck over here. Any help please

Comment: Could you help us out with what finalintermediate1 is? It seems to be your dataframe?

Comment: Hi Dustin yes it is the dataframe i am using to create xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?
Credit for the pretty printing:

[Use xml.etree.ElementTree to print nicely formatted xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402323/use-xml-etree-elementtree-to-print-nicely-formatted-xml-files/17402424)

[Pretty printing XML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python)

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="\t")

generated_on = str(datetime.datetime.now())
df = pd.DataFrame({'Field': ['FAPERF', 'FAPERF', 'FAPERF', 'FAPERF'],
                   'Form': ['LIVERID', 'LIVERID', 'LIVERID', 'LIVERID'],
                   'Folder': ['ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL'],
                   'Logline': ['9', '9', '9', '10'],
                   'Data': ['Yes', 'Blank', 'No', 'Yes']})

root = Element('ODM')
root.set('version', '1.0')
ClinicalData = SubElement(root, 'ClinicalData', {'text': 'yadeyadeyade'})
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    SubjectData = SubElement(ClinicalData, 'SubjectData', {'text': rows.Form})
    SiteRef = SubElement(SubjectData, 'SiteRef', {'text': rows.Logline})
    StudyEventData = SubElement(SiteRef, 'StudyEventData', {'text': rows.Data})
    FormData = SubElement(StudyEventData, 'FormData', {'text': rows.Field})
    ItemGroupData = SubElement(FormData, 'ItemGroupData', {'text': rows.Folder})

print(prettify(root))
```

Comment: I assumed all the subjects belong to one node called clinicaldata.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dustin, i got a perfect solution in a very short time. It worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot taking time in helping me.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Good luck with your project!