# Read an XML file with tags and indentation into a python variable

Tags: python, xml, file, parsing

Is there a way to read an entire XML file into a Python variable with tags and indentation?

```
data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<uimap>
    <page name="login">
        <uielement name="username">
             <locator>//input[@type='text']</locator>
        </uielement>
        <uielement name="password">
            <locator>//input[@type='password']</locator>
        </uielement>
    </page>
</uimap>
"""
```

This was a short example so I could manually type it in but if my XML files are really big, how can I read them into a python variable? Using fopen is not an option because it is reading all font size and styles too which is redundant in my case.

Comment: Can you read in XML files in Python? [Yes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). You'll have to be a bit more specific if you are stuck on something in particular, as it stands this question is very broad. If you want to keep the tags, you might as well just read it as a text file.

Comment: Please edit your post with this content. All the formatting is lost when you paste it into the comment section.

Comment: Why are indents necessary after you read it in, or are you planning to store it in a string?

Comment: I would imagine you would only need the indents to output it. In the case you might want to look at this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python

Comment: MxyL - I need to process the tags which is why I need them all stored as a string.

Comment: Also by process the tags, what exactly do you mean? Can you give more details on what you want to do with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import xml.dom.minidom

xmlObject = xml.dom.minidom.parse(xml_fname) # or xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_string)
pretty_xml_as_string = xmlObject.toprettyxml()
print(pretty_xml_as_string)
```

Answer taken from here: [Pretty printing XML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python)

This adds extra newlines. If you want the output to exactly look like your data you can try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlObject = ET.parse(xml_fname) # or ET.fromstring(xml_string)
pretty_xml_as_string = ET.tostring(xmlObject).decode()
print(pretty_xml_as_string)
```

Please note that this is for Python3.

[OP EDIT:] This is the one that worked for me

```
import lxml.etree as etree 
x = etree.parse("filename") 
print etree.tostring(x, pretty_print = True)
```

Comment: Ashwin - that did not work. I get the output like this "u'<?xml version="1.0" ?>\n<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>\n<w:wordDocument w:embeddedObjPresent="no" w:macrosPresent="no" w:ocxPresent="no" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemaLibrary/2003/core"....

Comment: import lxml.etree as etree

x = etree.parse("filename")
print etree.tostring(x, pretty_print = True)

Comment: - I tried this but the output I get is something like this   <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Monaco" w:h-ansi="Monaco" w:cs="Monaco"/>
            <wx:font wx:val="Monaco"/>
            <w:sz w:val="22"/>
            <w:sz-cs w:val="22"/>
            <w:u w:val="single"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>&lt;/uielement&gt;</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Monaco" w:h-ansi="Monaco" w:cs="Monaco"/>
            <wx:font wx:val="Monaco"/>
            <w:sz w:val="22"/>
            <w:sz-cs w:val="22"/>

Comment: Can you give me details on your xml? I tried this with data being the variable you specified in the question: 
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> x = ET.fromstring(data)
>>> print(ET.tostring(x).decode())
<uimap>
    <page name="login">
        <uielement name="username">
             <locator>//input[@type='text']</locator>
        </uielement>
        <uielement name="password">
            <locator>//input[@type='password']</locator>
        </uielement>
    </page>
</uimap>
>>>

Comment: Wish they would allow formatting in comments. Anyhow, when you try that, you get the string data as you specified on top with the correct formatting and indent.

Comment: Ashwin - thanks! that decode() was what I was missing. Instead of hard coding the "data" variable with the contents above. How would the same thing work if I had to read off of a file from an XML file at a certain location? Some of the XML files are huge to be hard coded.. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use ET.parse(<fileName>) where ET is as defined by my previous comment. Example: x = ET.parse('data.xml')

Comment: Comment #2 is what I used.

Comment: Can you please edit the answer with the version that you used? So that others can reference it easily. Thanks :)