# XML row structure in one row

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

Strange error occured, got a XML-file emailed to me which was wrongly formated. The info in the file was all in one row.

Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Text><otherText><printdate>2015-02-08</printdate>
```

Does anyone know a quick way to fix this by using a python script or something that has had the same error?

I want to make the file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Text>
<OtherText>
<Name>VH2</Name>
<PrintDate>2015-02-05</PrintDate>
```

Thanks!

Comment: How abount simply replacing `><` with `>\n<`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to print pretty, if you look into other XML libraries, such as lxml, it support pretty print.

```
import lxml.etree as etree

x = etree.parse("filename")
print etree.tostring(x, pretty_print = True)
```

However, you can also try this:
[Pretty printing XML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python)

Comment: Thank for you answer, although i get error message 
XMLSyntaxError: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document, line 1, column 665

Comment: I'll look into it and see if I can find a solution, although it seems to work on some files @Cui Heng

Answer (score 0):

If the XML is well formed this snippet will work

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xml.dom.minidom

def main():
    ugly_xml   = open('ugly.xml', 'r')
    pretty_xml = open('pretty.xml', 'w')

    xmll = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(ugly_xml.read())
    pretty_xml.write(xmll.toprettyxml()) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```