# XML Prettifying from file in Python

Tags: python, xml, prettify

I have an xml file which looks like the example below.

Many texts contain space as the start character, or have `\n` (newline) at the beginning, or other crazy stuff.  I'm working with `xml.etree.ElementTree`, and it is good to parse from this file.

But I want more! :)  I tried to prettify this mess, but without success. Tried many tutorials, but it always ends without pretty XML.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<import>
<article>
<name> Name with space
</name>
<source> Daily Telegraph
</source>
<number>72/2015
</number>
<page>10
</page>
<date>2015-03-26
</date>
<author> Tomas First
</author>
<description>Economy
</description>
<attachment>
</attachment>
<region>
</region>
<text>
 My text is here
</text>
</article>
<article>
<name> How to parse
</name>
<source> Internet article
</source>
<number>72/2015
</number>
<page>1
</page>
<date>2015-03-26
</date>
<author>Some author
</author>
<description> description
</description>
<attachment>
</attachment>
<region>
</region>
<text>
 My text here
</text>
</article>
</import>
```

When I tried another answers from SO it generates same file or more messy XML

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pretty printing XML in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python)

Comment: The newlines are a major contributor to your answers generating messy XML, by the way. If you don't need newlines in your data, you could just strip them all out with something like `tr -d` (albeit skipping the first line -- something easily done), then almost any XML processor would do the right thing when told to pretty-print.

Comment: @LukasGraf If you look at possible duplicate, they solve differrent problems. I mean this is not duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`bs4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#) can do it

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = BeautifulSoup(xmlstring, 'xml')

print doc.prettify()
```

Comment: Thank You. This helped me. I'm going to rewrite my code to reflect new pretty XML :)

Comment: Here is python script that i wrote. May it be useful for someone. It parse slovak language terms. Many Thanks.
http://pastebin.com/wj7TnN2f