# Open and Control an Application with Python

Tags: python, xml, notepad++

I'm using Python and I want to open Notepad++ with a specific .xml file. I am able to do that with the following code:

```
os.system('start notepad++.exe m1.xml')
```

What I want to do after this is use a plug in on Notepad called 'pretty print xml' that's under the plug-ins menu, but I have no idea how to access it with just code. I was wondering if anyone knows a way to access this item without installing plug ins for Python; I don't want to have to install a plug in for Python, I want to be able to use Python to control the Notepad++ application.

Basically, via code, I want to:

- Open the document [done]
- Open a menu in notepad
- Click a specific button in that menu
- Save the document

Comment: XY Problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python

Comment: Not wanting a library is kind of ... limiting.  Most of python's power comes from its library support.  I'd personally look at `pywinauto` for something like this (if you're insistent that you use menus / interact with np++).