# Python: Appending children to an already created XML file's root using XML DOM

Tags: python, xml, dom, elementtree

I'm totally new to XML and I'm stuck on how to append children to a root node of an already exisitng XML file using Python and XML DOM.  Right now I have this script to create an output file:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Document

doc = Document()

root_node = doc.createElement("notes")                          # Root
doc.appendChild(root_node)

object_node = doc.createElement("data")                         # Child
root_node.appendChild(object_node)

object_node.setAttribute("a_version", "something_v001.0001.ma") # Set attributes
object_node.setAttribute("b_user", "Me")
object_node.setAttribute("c_comment", "comment about file")

xml_file = open("C:/Temp/file_notes.xml", "w")                  # Append
xml_file.write(doc.toprettyxml())
xml_file.close()
```

This gives me an output file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<notes>
    <data a_version="Me" b_user="something_v001.0001.ma" c_comment="comment about file"/>
</notes>
```

I'd like to append future data to this file so it will look something like this after 2 additional versions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<notes>
    <data a_version="something_v001.0001.ma" b_user="Me" c_comment="comment about file"/>
    <data a_version="something_v001.0002.ma" b_user="You" c_comment="minor save"/>
    <data a_version="something_v002.0003.ma" b_user="Them" c_comment="major save"/>
</notes>
```

But every attempt I make at appending data comes out like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<notes>
    <data a_version="Me" b_user="something_v001.0001.ma" c_comment="comment about file"/>
</notes>
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<notes>
    <data a_version="Me" b_user="something_v001.0001.ma" c_comment="comment about file"/>
</notes>
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<notes>
    <data a_version="Me" b_user="something_v001.0001.ma" c_comment="comment about file"/>
</notes>
```

If anyone has any alternative methods to accomplish this task by using ElementTree that would be appreciated as well.  There seem to be a lot more resources, but I'm not sure how to implement the solution with Maya. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown us any code demonstrating "every attempt I make at appending data". But never mind, here is how you can use [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) to append new elements to an existing XML file.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

# Assume that we have an existing XML document with one "data" child
doc = ET.parse("file_notes.xml")
root = doc.getroot()

# Create 2 new "data" elements
data1 = ET.Element("data", {"a_version": "something_v001.0002.ma",
                            "b_user": "You",
                            "c_comment": "minor save"})
data2 = ET.Element("data", {"a_version": "something_v001.0003.ma",
                            "b_user": "Them",
                            "c_comment": "major save"})

# Append the new "data" elements to the root element of the XML document
root.append(data1)
root.append(data2)

# Now we have a new well-formed XML document. It is not very nicely formatted...
out = ET.tostring(root)

# ...so we'll use minidom to make the output a little prettier
dom = minidom.parseString(out)
print dom.toprettyxml()
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<notes>


    <data a_version="Me" b_user="something_v001.0001.ma" c_comment="comment about file"/>


    <data a_version="something_v001.0002.ma" b_user="You" c_comment="minor save"/>
    <data a_version="something_v001.0003.ma" b_user="Them" c_comment="major save"/>
</notes>
```

ElementTree does not have a built-in pretty-printer, so we use [minidom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html?highlight=minidom#module-xml.dom.minidom) for that. The output contains some superfluous whitespace, but it is better than what ElementTree can provide.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer so thoroughly, this is a huge help.  Would it be possible to get rid of the superfluous white space using another method, or is this expected with Element Tree?

Comment: *or is this expected with minidom?

Comment: The output from minidom shown in the answer is not perfect, but I wouldn't worry too much about some extra whitespace. There have been many questions about pretty-printing XML in Python. Here is one with several answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python.

Comment: Agreed, as long as the computer can read it I'm find (which it can :D).  I'd just like to mention that that each time I append data it's adding more blank lines exponentially.  So a file that that has 15 lines of appended data is around 300 lines.  Is this expected/a problem?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem. You could simply skip pretty-printing altogether; my answer works without it. It is just a convenience to make the resulting XML structure easier to read for a human.

Comment: Assuming of course that you are going to process the XML file in some way, and not just look at it.

Comment: Since Python 3.9, ElementTree has a pretty-printer: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.indent.