# python ElementTree: update subtree

Tags: python, subtree

Say I have this xml file:

```
<root>
  <abc>SomeTree1</abc>
  <abc>SomeTree2</abc>
  ...
</root>
```

and I want to make some operations on the elements in "abc".
so I do something like this:

```
for element in root.findall('./abc')
    ** new_element = function1(element) **
```

(function1 operates on element and returns an updated version of it).
How can I update `root` with the new_element instead of element?
(Maybe something like: element.set(new_element) )?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you mean by update? Any changes you do to your the elements will be automatically stored in root.

Comment: @Plasma I guess it was worth mentioning that these changing are happening inside functions.
(I'll edit the question so it will be clearer from now on)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `root` of your tree to the function, then use `ElementTree.SubElement` to add a new element to your `root`. I've worked with your example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def function(root):
    new_element = ET.SubElement(root, "abc")
    new_element.set("name", "Jonas")
    new_element.text = "This is text"

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

# Before
print ET.tostring(root)

for element in root.findall("./abc"):
    function(root)

# After
print ET.tostring(root)
```

Before:

```
<root>
  <abc>SomeTree1</abc>
</root>
```

After:

```
<root>
  <abc>SomeTree1</abc>
  <abc name="Jonas">This is text</abc>
</root>
```

Note that I've polished the xml myself, it's not pretty per default. If you want pretty-print, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python) answer.

**Edit**: Sorry, I thought from the comments that you wanted to add a new element, not replace the current one. For replacing that element, you could either modify the function above to take in an element, then add a new element before removing the original, or you could just modify the existing element directly:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def function(element):
    element.text = "New text"
    element.tag = "New tag"
    element.set("name", "Jonas")

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

# Before
print ET.tostring(root)

for element in root.findall("./abc"):
    function(element)

# After
print ET.tostring(root)
```

Before:

```
<root>
  <abc>SomeTree1</abc>
</root>
```

After:

```
<root>
  <New tag name="Jonas">New text</New tag>
</root>
```

Comment: That is what I tried, and the elements were not updated on root. I'll see again if I did something wrong but I don't think so.
Changing the value of element in a function doesn't change it outside that function.