# Pretty printing XML with a core install of Python 3.2

Tags: python, xml

I've looked at: [Pretty printing XML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python)
This doesn't suit my needs, because for various reasons - I've got a base install of Python 3.2 on Windows, but no ability to add modules. (user privs).

The suggested solution is:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

xml = xml.dom.minidom.parse(xml_fname) 
pretty_xml_as_string = xml.toprettyxml()
```

This turns:

```
<root>
    <node>content</node>
    <node attrib="value">more content</node>
</root>
```

Into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>


        <node>content</node>


        <node attrib="value">more content</node>


</root>
```

It does work if you've got:

```
<root><node>content</node><node attrib="value">more content</node></root>
```

So I would assume it's preserving linefeeds, but adding extra indent/whitespace. I appreciate the answer is *probably* 'use a module' - but what I'm looking for is something that can turn arbitrary formatted `xml` into consistently pretty-printed.

(And using a core install module if at all possible).

Comment: Was your input generated under Windows? If so then it is possible that `toprettyxml` expects UNIX-style line endings (LF). Try replacing in the input all CRLF with LF.

Comment: It was, yes. I shall try that.