# add element in a existing xml file python

Tags: python, xml, celementtree

I have a existing xml file as following:

```
<vehicleTravelTimeMeasurements>
        <vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement name="ckkkkkkkkkk" no="2">
            <start link="1" pos="3.864983"/>
            <end link="3" pos="23.275375"/>
        </vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement>
        <vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement name="" no="3">
            <start link="1" pos="3.864983"/>
            <end link="2" pos="13.275375"/>
        </vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement>
</vehicleTravelTimeMeasurements>
```

I am trying to construct the same format as shown above by using xml.etree.cElementTree, and add them into the xml correctly:

```
new = ET.Element("vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement", name = "kkk", no = "4")
newsub1 =  ET.Element("start", link = "1", pos="3.88888")
newsub2 = ET.Element("end",link = "3", pos = "3.88888")
```

could someone help me out with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `new.append(newsub1)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wanted to use `SubElement` and add the `start` and `end` elements to the `vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement` element. Then insert that newly created element at position 2, since 0 and 1 are already occupied.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def indent(elem, level=0):
    i = "\n" + level*"  "
    if len(elem):
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
            elem.text = i + "  "
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
        for elem in elem:
            indent(elem, level+1)
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = i

xml = '''<vehicleTravelTimeMeasurements>
        <vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement name="ckkkkkkkkkk" no="2">
            <start link="1" pos="3.864983"/>
            <end link="3" pos="23.275375"/>
        </vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement>
        <vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement name="" no="3">
            <start link="1" pos="3.864983"/>
            <end link="2" pos="13.275375"/>
        </vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement>
</vehicleTravelTimeMeasurements>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
new = ET.Element("vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement", name = "kkk", no = "4")
newsub1 = ET.SubElement(new, "start", link = "1", pos="3.88888")
newsub2 = ET.SubElement(new, "end",link = "3", pos = "3.88888")
root.insert(2, new)
indent(root)
with open('test.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(ET.tostring(root))
```

Comment: yes. you right. they are same. but my question is when I open the file as xml. the new added elements are not shown structured as the original [0] or [1] element.

Comment: @Condo_programmer my latest edit writes to a file now

Comment: thank you so much! never mind. it's about notepad ++ issue. the problem sovled

Answer (score 0):

Short version / ***Updates & Edits:***

The only thing you need to do is (A) add `newsub1` and `newsub2` to `new`. And (B) add `new` to `root`.

```
root = ET.fromstring(xml)  # or whichever way you're getting `root`
# these 3 lines form your code:
new = ET.Element('vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement', name="kkk", no="4")
newsub1 = ET.Element('start', link='1', pos='3.88888')
newsub2 = ET.Element('end', link='3', pos='3.88888')
# the next steps to add
new.append(newsub1)
new.append(newsub2)
root.append(new)
```

Note that (A) & (B) can be done in any order and this can be shortened, as below:

```
>>> root = ET.fromstring(xml)
>>> new = ET.Element('vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement', name="kkk", no="4")
>>> root.append(new)  # note that I've immediately added `new`
>>> ET.SubElement(new, 'start', link='1', pos='3.88888')
<Element 'start' at 0x24707b8>
>>> ET.SubElement(new, 'end', link='3', pos='3.88888')
<Element 'end' at 0x24ea978>
>>> # there's no need to store the subelements in `newsub1` and
... # `newsub2` if you don't need to do anything with them
...
>>> indent(root)
>>> print ET.tostring(root)
<vehicleTravelTimeMeasurements>
  <vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement name="ckkkkkkkkkk" no="2">
    <start link="1" pos="3.864983" />
    <end link="3" pos="23.275375" />
  </vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement>
  <vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement name="" no="3">
    <start link="1" pos="3.864983" />
    <end link="2" pos="13.275375" />
  </vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement>
  <vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement name="kkk" no="4">
    <start link="1" pos="3.88888" />
    <end link="3" pos="3.88888" />
  </vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement>
</vehicleTravelTimeMeasurements>
```

Notes:

1. I've added `new` to `root` just after creating it.
2. Use [`append`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.append) instead of `insert` if you know you're always appending, instead of needing to keep track of the `no`'s in your original xml

   - unless you need to read that anyway to calculate the next '`no`' attribute
3. `ET.SubElement(new)` updates `new` (and `root`) even though `new` has already been appended.
4. There's no need to store the subelements in `newsub1` and `newsub2` if you don't need to do anything with them.

   - First method (like yours) creates the elements and then adds them to root or new.
   - Second method uses `ET.SubElement(new, ...)` to add the elements to its parent.
5. The [function `indent` is from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4590052/1431750), which [quotes this source](http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm#prettyprint).

Re # 4.2 above, could also be done as:

```
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
new = ET.SubElement(root, 'vehicleTravelTimeMeasurement', name="kkk", no="4")
# `new` is already created as a subelement of `root` and appended
ET.SubElement(new, 'start', link='1', pos='3.88888')
ET.SubElement(new, 'end', link='3', pos='3.88888')
```

From the [Subelement docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement):

> This function creates an element instance, and **appends** it to an existing element.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. could you please be more specific?

Comment: There was no `add_element`, I was thinking of `ET.SubElement(<parent>, ...)`. So that part of my answer was totally wrong. Also, the last code snippet in the edited answer is the _smallest_ change you'd need to make to do what you wanted. :-)