# Write Python NTLM XML response to local XML file

Tags: python, xml, ntlm

I have been looking all over to see if there is a simple way to write an NTLM response to a local XML file. How would I go about doing this?

```
import requests
import ntlm3 as ntlm
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

SITE = "website.com/_api/..."
USERNAME = 'user'
PASSWORD = 'pass'

response = requests.get(SITE, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(USERNAME,PASSWORD))

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the NTLM `response.text` is a well-formed XML, simply dump the text value to file:

```
xmlfile = open('Output.xml', 'wb')
xmlfile.write(response_text)
xmlfile.close()
```

And to pretty print the output to file, consider `lxml` module:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

...

dom = ET.fromstring(response.text)
tree_out = ET.tostring(dom, pretty_print=True)

xmlfile = open('Output.xml', 'wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

Comment: If the file is kind of jumbled should I use ElementTree? This does not actually create the file right I need to create a file named "Output.xml"

Comment: Do you mean [pretty print](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python)? Minidom and lxml modules can do so.

Comment: Also when I create the XML file and run the code I get 
    xmlfile.write(response.text)
    io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Comment: Whoops! See update with the write binary, `wb` argument.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way I can do this without having to create the file manually?

Comment: Not quite familiar with [NTLM library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/python-ntlm/). See if there is an output to file functionality, but it seems response just migrates to string object for users to manipulate further for end use needs. For pretty print, you would need another operation.