# Python xmlformatter is breaking my ampersands

Tags: python, xml

I wrote a Python script to add a node to an xml file. Although it works fine, the xml comes out oddly formatted. For example, a new node is added, and if it's the last one for a parent node, the parent node closing tag is now immediately after the new node's closing tag. This is fine technically, but we wanted the xml to "look" good too.

So I installed xmlformatter add-on for Python. Although it lets me format the look of the xml properly, it is changing the encoded ampersands in my text values to actual ampersands, thus breaking the xml.

I tried googling this but couldn't find any mention of it. Can anybody suggest a way to prevent this? I tried changing the encoding_output to various values or eliminating it altogether, but nothing helps.

Thanks...

Comment: Do you mean it is taking this `&amp;` and turning it into `&`?  And is it doing it everywhere (Classes, Parents, Children, Attributes, etc.) or just certain parts of the XML?

Comment: Yes, @dblclik, exactly. Here is how it should look: `<app appcode="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts" redirect="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts.tob"/>
        <app appcode="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts.alerts" redirect="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts.tob"/>
        <app appcode="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts.export" redirect="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts.tob"/>
        <app appcode="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts.text" redirect="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts.tob"/>`.  Happens wherever the `code`&amp;`code` appears.

Comment: I know it's low-tech, but if we suppose that your output was stored as `pretty_xml = xmlformatter(orig_xml)` (sorry, I'm using theoretical functions here to give you the idea), could you use Python's `re` package to just do then `final_xml = re.sub('&','&amp;',pretty_xml)`?

Comment: Can't use, because & is included in an html tag with CDATA section, and that would also be "fixed".  Best would be to figure out why xmlformatter is "formatting" the `&amp;`, right?

Comment: Did you try the `preserve` argument to the `xmlformatter.Formatter()` initialization call?  It looks like you could pass `preserve=['&amp;']` and it should preserve that element (sorry if that still doesn't work, I'm going off of their documentation and it's _meh_ at best)

Comment: Do you have an actual working string you could provide?  I installed xmlformatter so I could try to help out here if you have a sample XML string or file!

Comment: `preserve` may work, but not good idea, because what about the next encoding we use? We would have to tweak the script each time we caught an error.

Comment: Can't send proprietary xml file, but here's a snippet:  `<integratedAppMap>
        <app appcode="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts" redirect="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts.tob"/>
        <app appcode="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts.alerts" redirect="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts.tob"/>
        <app appcode="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts.export" redirect="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts.tob"/>
        <app appcode="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts.text" redirect="Mobile Banking &amp; Alerts.tob"/>
    </integratedAppMap>`
Thanks...

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this answer here work?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1206856/1607105  It uses the built-in `xml` package and the `topretty()` function seems to leave the `&amp;` alone

Comment: I saw that one also. They want me to use lxml, not dom object (don't know if they are mutually exclusive or not).  I'm going to quit on this thread. I found out if I send the parser `parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)` it properly formats and I don't need xmlformatter anymore.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution to this?  I've started looking at  `xml.parsers.expat.ParserCreate()` because I believe the issue is in there.

Comment: No, never figured it out, but see my last comment above. Don't need xmlformatter anymore.