# ElementTree Write to an XML

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

What's the easiest way to write an edited XML root to a new file? This is what I have so far and it's throwing **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'write'** 
PS: I can't use any other api besides ElementTree.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment
from ElementTree_pretty import prettify
tree = ET.parse('file-to-be-edited.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

#Process XML here

ET.write('file-after-edits.xml')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tree` is a `ElementTree` object which provides a [`write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) method to write the tree. For example:

```
#Process XML here
tree.write('file-after-edits.xml', encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Silly mistake on my part. Is there any way possible to prettify the generated file?

Comment: You could use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) which provides a compatible API to that of `ElementTree`. Its `tree.write()` method accepts a `pretty_print=True` argument.

Comment: Or use `minidom`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python

Answer (score 1):

**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'write'** is saying that you cannot call the write method directly from ElementTree class, it is not a static method, try using `tree.write('file-after-edits.xml')`, tree is your object from ElementTree.

Comment: Anyway possible to prettify the generated file?