# How to write the content of etree.dump to a file

Tags: xml, elementtree

The content of code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import sys
tree = etree.parse('in.xml')
out = open('out.xml','w')
out.write(etree.dump(tree))
out.close()
```

However, once I run it, i get empty content on out.xml.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Regards,
Ashish

Comment: Use `tree.write()` as it says here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39338941/407651. `dump()` should be used for debugging only: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=elementtree#xml.etree.ElementTree.dump.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ElementTree Write to an XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338733/elementtree-write-to-an-xml)

Comment: Thanks!  After changing the code as below, it's working fine.

import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import sys
tree = etree.parse('in1.xml')
out = open('out.xml','w')
root=tree.getroot()
y=etree.tostring(root, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8')
out.write(y)
out.close()

Answer (score 0):

After changing the code as below, it's working fine.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import sys
tree = etree.parse('in1.xml')
out = open('out.xml','w')
root=tree.getroot()
y=etree.tostring(root, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8')
out.write(y)
out.close()
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `tree.write()`? There is no need for `out = open('out.xml','w')`.