# Pretty print xml in python (+more requirements)

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree, pretty-print

I have an `ElementTree` object in Python 3.5.

I need to write it into a file with few requirements:

- With indentation (pretty print of 2 spaces).
- Without the version line.
- Empty tags should appear with both opening and closing tags (for example

`<sometag>
</sometag>`
and not

`<sometag/>`)

### EDIT

Okay, so far I have this code

        `pp_xml = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(self._root)).\
            toprettyxml(indent='  ')
        # Remove the version line
        pp_xml = pp_xml[pp_xml.find('\n')+1:]
        ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(pp_xml)).write(self._out_filepath,
                                                    short_empty_elements=False)`

Which does almost everything I asked for, except that that empty tags appear like this: 
`<sometag></sometag>`

And I need them to be in new lines like this:

`<sometag>
</sometag>`

Comment: You should post what you've tried.

Comment: Added, thanks (Too short comment).

Comment: Tempted to vote to close as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/749796/407651

Comment: It does not answer my question. Also, I can't use lxml. Only builtin modules.

Comment: Okay, so I can manually remove the version line (the first line) simply by `pp_xml = pp_xml[pp_xml.find('\n')+1:]` Now I only need to find a way to make 2 lines empty tags.

Comment: I suppose you'll have to walk through all empty elements and set their `text` property to `\n`.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but it's not great because it ruins the indentation. The closing tag then appears non-indented, at the beginning of the next line.