# Python/XML: Pretty-printing ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, pretty-print

I construct XML using [The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and I would like to be able to pretty-print

- individual nodes (for inspection) as well as
- the whole document (to a file, for future examination).

I can use use [`ET.write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) to write my XML to file and then pretty-print it using many suggestions in [Pretty printing XML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/749796/850781). However, this requires me to serialize and then deserialize the XML (to disk or to [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html)) just to serialize it again prettily - which is clearly suboptimal.

So, is there a way to pretty-print an `xml.etree.ElementTree`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) say, in the `write` method:

> *file* is a file name, or a file object opened for writing.

This includes a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) object. So:

```
outfile = cStringIO.StringIO()
tree.write(of)
```

Then you can just pretty-print `outfile` using your favorite method—just `outfile.seek(0)` then pass `outfile` itself to a function that takes a file, or pass `outfile.getvalue()` to a function that takes a string.

---

However, notice that many of the ways to pretty-print XML in the question you linked don't even need this. For example:

- [`lxml.etree.tostring` (answer #2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/749839/908494): `lxml.etree` is a near-perfect superset of the stdlib etree, so if you're going to use it for pretty-printing, just use it to build the XML in the first place.
- [Effbot `indent`/`prettyprint` (answer #3)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4590052/908494): This expects an `ElementTree` tree, which is exactly what you already have, not a string or file.

Comment: `StringIO` is serializing & deserializing - nfg.

Comment: @sds Changing your question to make existing answers irrelevant really isn’t helpful.

Comment: apologies - however, you gotta agree that the serializing & deserializing for pp is nfg ;-)

Comment: More to the point, your new question makes no sense. If you want to use a function that takes a serialized XML document, obviously you have to serialize it. Alternatively, you can use a function that takes an ET tree—there are examples of that on the very question you linked, and in this answer.

Comment: @sds I don’t know what “nfg” means, but if the cost of pretty-printing XML is acceptable, I assume the cost of serializing XML is acceptable, because pretty-printing inherently means serializing.

Comment: @sds Then why did you even ask? I just linked to an answer on the same question you linked to in your question…

Comment: I did not realize that lxml was a drop-in replacement for xml - basically, you can elide your answer to contain just that. ;-)

Comment: The stringio method means: (1) serialize the XML to stringio (2) deserialize the string into dom (3) pretty-serialize it. IOW, to get a pretty serialization, I have to serialize *twice* and deserialize once. This, IMO, is "no freaking good". ;-)

Comment: @sds Sure, but 90%+ of the time, the performance cost of printing your XML is a tiny fraction of the what matters, so tripling it is nothing. Because when that _isn’t_ true, there’s a very good chance the stdlib etree isn’t nearly fast enough in the first place.

Comment: It's not really a matter of performance but rather of aesthetics. Doesn't doing the same work twice make you cringe?

Comment: @sds Sure, but I usually take it as a sign that I’m using the wrong data structure. When you really do need to convert from one to another, you’ve already hit the code smell, so looking for a magic way to do it without iterating rather than backing up and asking why you have the wrong data structure is usually the wrong approach.

Answer (score 3):

I was having issues using pretty print. Digging more into it I found the below solution which worked for me.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
from xml.dom import minidom

root = etree.Element("root")
animal = etree.SubElement(root, "animal")
etree.SubElement(animal, "pet").text = "dog"

xmlstr = 
minidom.parseString(etree.toString(root)).toprettyxml(indent = "   ")
print (xmlstr)
```

Returns the result in XML format

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question improves its long-term value.