# Is there any way I can prettify an XML element before appending it to a bigger XML file?

Tags: python, xml

I'm parsing an XML file and need to modify only some sections, so I don't need to re-write the entire XML.
My problem is the initial XML is pretty and nicely aligned, but the element(s) I'm appending is(are) all in one line and it doesn't look pretty at all.

Is there any way I could prettify the element(s) before appending it(them) using only Python's standard library?

Comment: Start by looking at the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/749796/407651

Comment: I would try copying an element, and appending it elsewhere, then change the content.