# Issue formatting xml data in python that is present as a string

Tags: python, formatting

i have this string variable `res.text` that has XML content inside it, is there a way in python to format such data?

```
>> res.text
'<config> <header>'abc'</header'></config>'
```

the actual data i have is about 2000 lines, wanted to better view the data like below:

```
<config>                                                                                                                                             
   <header> 
     'abc'
   </header>
</config>
```

Comment: How should it be formatted?

Comment: updated above, thanks

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python