# Python 3 save the output of ElementTree.dump() to xml file?

Tags: python, xml

I have this xml file located at path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20210331_124249\Datastore_GlobalRules\Datastore_Discovery.xml", it is a one-line-only xml file, you can view it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iPi2XK6AR7X0gJzcKA2ult-Wt4GzuRQx/view?usp=sharing).

It is pretty ugly and not very readable and hard to get information from it, so I Google searched for a method to beautify the xml file with Python, and I found this question:[Pretty printing XML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/749796/15290516)

The first two answers didn't give me what I wanted, the printed xml is still ugly, but the [third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4590052/15290516) did give me what wanted:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def indent(elem, level=0):
    i = "\n" + level*"  "
    j = "\n" + (level-1)*"  "
    if len(elem):
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
            elem.text = i + "  "
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
        for subelem in elem:
            indent(subelem, level+1)
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = j
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = j
    return elem        

xml = ElementTree.parse('C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Setup Bootstrap/Log/20210331_124249/Datastore_GlobalRules/Datastore_Discovery.xml').getroot()
indent(xml)
ElementTree.dump(xml)
```

This is the output: [output.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rb9Tzry1ELH-1tK4934zeqlUMDAUqXCl/view?usp=sharing)

However I can't redirect the output to an xml file;

I first tried to use this method:

```
out = open('C:/Output.xml','w')
out.write(ElementTree.dump(xml))
out.close()
```

It gave this error:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
```

Tried this:

```
xml.write('C:/output.xml')
```

It gave this error:

```
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'write'
```

If I use this:

```
ElementTree.dump(xml).write('C:/output.xml')
```

Results this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

How can I redirect the output of ElementTree.dump(xml) to an xml file? I am sorry if this question is too trivial but I am very new to Python, I don't know much, how can I do this? Any help is truly appreciated.

---

P.S. About how I got the output file, I copy-pasted the output from the console window.

Comment: you should check out the documentation for `dump` https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.dump. It says `Writes an element tree or element structure to sys.stdout. This function should be used for debugging only.`

Comment: In Python 3.9, there is a built-in `indent` method for pretty-printing with ElementTree: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.indent

Comment: @mzjn Nice one, i didnt know that, i just posted an answer using lxml cause of its in built pretty print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dump` method dumps the output to `sys.stdout` you could use the lxml module which has a built in pretty print feature.

```py
from lxml import etree

data = r"""<a><b>hello</b><c>world</c><d><e>foo</e><f>bar</f></d></a>"""
tree = etree.fromstring(data)
print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<a>
  <b>hello</b>
  <c>world</c>
  <d>
    <e>foo</e>
    <f>bar</f>
  </d>
</a>
```

However if you did want to use only ElementTree since its built in and use your own func, then you need to call the tostring method not dump.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def indent(elem, level=0):
    i = "\n" + level*"  "
    j = "\n" + (level-1)*"  "
    if len(elem):
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
            elem.text = i + "  "
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
        for subelem in elem:
            indent(subelem, level+1)
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = j
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = j
    return elem

data = r"""<a><b>hello</b><c>world</c><d><e>foo</e><f>bar</f></d></a>"""
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(data)
indent(tree)
print(ElementTree.tostring(tree).decode())
```

but as you see its not actually as pretty as it should be, not everything is nested correctly

**OUTPUT**

```
<a>
  <b>hello</b>
<c>world</c>
<d>
    <e>foo</e>
  <f>bar</f>
  </d>
</a>
```

Comment: Well thank you for your answer, your answer is good, but here is just a little reminder, you missed the part to redirect the output: `out=open('C:/Path/to/file','w')`, `print(ElementTree.tostring(tree).decode(), file=out)`, `out.close()`. I got the steps by myself though I can't have redirected the output using the wrong method; Anyway thanks and please include the actual code to redirect the output.

Comment: Well your fundamental issue was converting the xml into a nice string to write to a file. you already knew how to write a string to a file so I didnt see it relevant to include that in the answer. Its the same reason i didnt include loading the xml from a file, instead just from a string, as the problem you had was converting the xml to a pretty string not loading a file or writing to a file.