# how to xml add a new element to a new line

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml

Executing the code:

```
parser = ET.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False, )
tree = ET.parse(f'copy_{xml_file}', parser)
root[0].insert(0, ET.Element("type"))
root.write("test.xml", pretty_print=True)
```

And the element I added creates not on a new line but in front of another element, it turns out the form:

```
    <firstTeg>327</firstTeg>
    <secondTeg>1.0</secondTeg><type/>
```

I need to get this kind of:

```
    <firstTeg>327</firstTeg>
    <secondTeg>1.0</secondTeg>
    <type/>
```

How do I create a new tag on a new line?

Comment: For xml it does not matter

Comment: Did you try to add `ET.indent(tree, '  ')` before `write`?

Comment: @balderman unfortunately, this matters to the person working further with this xml)

Comment: @Parolla Until you pointed it out, I didn't even know. It really works. Could you please write this below as an answer, I will answer it as a solution to my question, for future seekers

Comment: This is about "pretty-printing". There are many existing questions and answers about it already. For example https://stackoverflow.com/q/749796/407651

Comment: @mzjn You are right, but, for example, the key `pretty_print=True` in the `tree.write` method did not help me. `xml.dom.minidom' - it is necessary to additionally import and configure, I have also met `remove_blank_text = True` advised, but there is no token. And according to the method proposed above - just one added line solves this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
ET.indent(tree, '  ')
```

line before

```
root.write("test.xml", pretty_print=True)
```

**Note**: [Feature available](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.indent) from Python 3.9

Comment: The question is about lxml. `indent()` was added in lxml 4.5: https://lxml.de/4.5/changes-4.5.0.html.

Answer (score 1):

```
parser = ET.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False, )
tree = ET.parse(f'copy_{xml_file}', parser)
new_elem = ET.Element("type")
new_elem.tail ="\n    "
root[0].insert(0, new_elem)
root.write("test.xml", pretty_print=True)
```

output:

```
<firstTeg>327</firstTeg>
<secondTeg>1.0</secondTeg>
<type/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).